# Anyone knows how create a javascript "effect" for slide the website

Tags: javascript, effect

My boss (my pointed hairy boss) want an effect in javascript for show an advertise. The effect he wants is some like this. When the user enter the site, a banner must appear and "push" the website out the screen, and that space must be use for the banner. After a few seconds, the banner must to disappear, and the website restore. I looked at various places for javascript libraries effects and i didn't found anything similar. Do you know some effects with similar characteristics?

I already look at jquery effects and other libraries, but the effects isn't exactly as the effects my boss want. I saw the effects one time, when he show me a similar banner in www.latercera.cl, but sadly the ad campaign isn't there anymore. I don't know how better explain this effects because my native language isn't English, is Spanish
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you search for "jquery slide" in Google? Did you not find anything relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Like how StackOverflow works when you get that yellow banner along the top?

This site uses jQuery. Check out the effects available there, for example [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, and see if it has what you need. jQuery has a library of canned UI widgets, and it also has animation methods like sliding and transitioning that may enable you to build your own effect easily.